# How do I add a keyboard shortcut to activate/disable a VSCode extension?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I want to be able to turn certain extensions on and off with a keyboard shortcut. But didn't found out how to do keybindings for extension activation

Specifically I wanna do this for VSCodeVim. So that I can use it more often and become more used to using Vi

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To toggle Vim mode in Vscode do the following:

1. Use 'CTRl+Shift+P' to open vscode command palette
2. type 'vim toggle', you will see 'Vim: Toggle Vim Mode' option
3. select it and press enter to toggle vim mode.

To add keybinding (shortcut) for toggling :

1. open command palette using 'Ctrl+shift+p'
2. type 'shortcuts'
3. select 'Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts' and press enter
4. search 'toggleVim'
5. click on 'Keybinding' column
6. press the buttons you want for the shortcut and press enter

Not every extension can be disabled by this method, But all extensions can be disabled or enabled for a particular workspace.

Comment: Thanks man was a perfect answer 

Only way to improve it would be how to do it in dotfiles as well 

Comment: `Use 'CTRl+Shift+P' to open vscode command palette` vim toggle not found?

Comment: @AayushNeupane do you have vscodevim installed? Which extension are you trying to diable?

Comment: of course i have  installed vscode vim, i am using it , but cant find vim toggle.

Comment: I have the same problem as Aayush. The extension is installed, but I can't find that command.

Comment: in your `keybindings.json` file, add this with the shortcut of your choice after key `{"key": "ctrl+shift+v", "command": "toggleVim"}`, and this will activate or deactivate the extension on the fly